# let does not execute the second expression in the body

Tags: clojure

If I understand the [documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/let) right, I can write this:

```
(let [a 5 b 10]
  (print a)
  (print b))
```

This works as expected and prints out 5 and 10. I use this mechanism in this code snippet (The full code is [here](https://github.com/arg-games/ldview) if you need more reference):

```
(defn create! [fields]
  (let [username (user/unique-user (:author fields))
        competition-id (:id (competition/latest))]
    (if-not (exists? (:ld_uid fields))
      (insert entries (values {
                               :ld_uid (:ld_uid fields)
                               :title (:title fields)
                               :description (:description fields)
                               :type (:type fields)
                               :user_id (:id username)
                               :competition_id competition-id})))
    (for [link (:links fields)]
      (source/create! (:id (by-ld-uid (:ld_uid fields))) (:url link) (:title link)))))
```

the problem is, the `for` expression is **not executed**. The statements as its own works as expected but in this code above the `insert` expression is executed but the `for` not. Do I oversee something? I am out of ideas whats going wrong here :(

Comment: The `for` expression is lazy. Wrap with a `dorun` or change to a `doseq`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not what you think: Clojure's `for` uses lazy evaluation -- that is, if you don't do anything with what it returns, the loop never runs.

That's very useful for long-running loops over massive sequences that you don't even need in their entirety, but when you're actually trying to run side effects, lazy evaluation is something you need to stay away from.

You want to use `doseq` instead (http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doseq).